# Selenium IJavaScriptExecutor isn't working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

For whatever reason IJavaScriptExecutor doesn't seem to be working in Selenium, for me at least.

Potentially changes have been made to the library and I'm referencing incorrectly? But I have no syntax errors.

code is -

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

js.ExecuteScript("alert('Hello');");
```

Comment: have you launched the home page before executing the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using a [RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver.htm) instance which does not support JavaScript like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net)?

It should be normally possible to execute JavaScript from the major modern web browsers

[image]

Make sure to use the most recent version of [Selenium.WebDriver package from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) and the appropriate package for the browser, you're trying to automate, i.e. [Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/)

Check out [Selenium with C Sharp](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+with+C+Sharp) to see the project setup instructions, you might also be interested in a [sample project](https://github.com/seetest-io/csharp-selenium-first-test) you can use as a basis.